# Will this Win8 upgrade option be available on OEM copies of Win7?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, windows-8

I just heard about how, reportedly, if a Windows 7 computer is bought afte June 2, an upgrade to Windows 8 will be available for a discounted price (reportedly $15.99). ([source](http://www.winsupersite.com/blog/supersite-blog-39/windows8/windows-8-pro-pc-upgrade-cost-15-143077))

I was wondering if this would also be available for system builders buying just Windows 7, such as [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116992) OEM version?

Comment: Typical tactic to get the W8 "sales" numbers up and make it look like more of a success than it is in the early weeks-months of release. Attractive offer I must say, the upgrade is for W8 Pro, regardless of what version W7 you purchased with a PC. Paul Thurrott is a very reliable source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the upgrade offer applies to all OEM copies of Windows 7 (except Starter), according to Microsoft's published [program terms](https://windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-US/Home/ProgramInfo).

Comment: However, my question is if this applies when you buy Windows seperately. It says in the [FAQ](https://windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-US/Home/Faq) that it must be preinstalled to qualify.

Comment: OEM System Builder copies of Windows are intended to be preinstalled on customers' PCs by system builders. That's the whole point.

Comment: so you're saying that the System Builder copy is not the same as the FPP/retail one which is excluded?

Comment: No, System Builder copies are OEM copies, legally the same as those that come preinstalled on Dell, HP, Gateway etc. They are intended for small business type of computer stores to install on PCs that they sell.

Answer (score 7):

My assumption would be no.  Generally these programs (as it was with windows 7 and windows vista) are in part sponsored directly by computer manufacturer as a way to not have their prebuilt machine sales slump in the face of an operating system release.  For what its worth, I would recommend waiting.  Usually the details of this style of promotion are pretty convoluted, and you can get burned if you arent careful.

Source:  Worked for a retailer during the Windows Vista>Windows 7 Discount coupon era.

Edit: Wow, downvotes galore all of a sudden.....

Comment: "Worked for a retailer during the Windows Vista>Windows 7 Discount coupon era." You poor soul! What a nightmare Vista was.

Comment: @Moab: Haha, thanks.  Sadly I worked for the retailer during the Vista launch, watched it fail miserably, and then worked for the same retailer when 7 came out, and went through the whole process of upgrading vista machines to 7.  I'd upgrade 100 machines from Vista to 7 if it meant I never had to upgrade an XP machine to Vista ever again....

Comment: I worked many forums helping with patching Vista to work, this was before sp1, what a pain, I started using Vista at RC so I could get familiar with it to help on forums, worst OS ever released, lucky for me I did not have to meet face to face with customers.

Answer (score 3):

one word "YES"

It's a MS upgrade offer for ANY windows based systems from XP home to Win7 Ult, store bought or "OEM" system that came with your HP, Dell, Samsung, or whatever.

it's a FULL version of Win8 "PRO" not home.

If you buy a PC from June 2 2012 to Feb 2013 you can get the "upgrade" for 15 bucks as a download, and even get the MS entertainment center free as another download.

Comment: I'm not talking about buying PCs, I'm talking about buying just Windows